# Achieving C# "readonly" behavior in C++

Tags: c++, singleton, extern

this is my first question on stack overflow, so be gentle.

Let me first explain the exact behavior I would like to see. If you are familiar with C# then you know that declaring a variable as "readonly" allows a programmer to assign some value to that variable exactly once. Further attempts to modify the variable will result in an error.

What I am after: I want to make sure that any and all single-ton classes I define can be predictably instantiated exactly once in my program (more details at the bottom).

My approach to realizing my goal is to use extern to declare a global reference to the single-ton (which I will later instantiate at a time I choose. What I have sort of looks like this,

```
namespace Global
{
    extern Singleton& mainInstance; // not defined yet, but it will be later!
}

int main()
{
    // now that the program has started, go ahead and create the singleton object
    Singleton& Global::mainInstance = Singleton::GetInstance(); // invalid use of qualified name
    Global::mainInstance = Singleton::GetInstance(); // doesn't work either :( 
}

class Singleton
{
    /* Some details ommited */

    public:
        Singleton& GetInstance()
        {
            static Singleton instance; // exists once for the whole program
            return instance;
        }
}
```

However this does not really work, and I don't know where to go from here.

Some details about what I'm up against:

I'm concerned about threading as I am working on code that will deal with game logic while
communicating with several third-party processes and other processes I will create. Eventually I would have
to implement some kind of synchronization so multiple threads could access the information
in the Singleton class without worry. Because I don't know what kinds of optimizations I might
like to do, or exactly what threading entails (never done a real project using it), I was thinking
that being able to predictably control when Singletons were instantiated would be a Good Thing.

Imagine if Process A creates Process B, where B contains several Singletons distributed against multiple files and/or libraries. It could be a real nightmare if I can not reliably ensure the order these singleton objects are instantiated (because they could depend on each other, and calling methods on a NULL object is generally a Bad Thing).

If I were in C# I would just use the readonly keyword, but is there any way I can implement this
(compiler supported) behavior in C++? Is this even a good idea? Thanks for any feedback.

---

*Edit*

If I was locked in to following the code example above, the selected answer would be the easiest way to do what I needed. I decided to change the pattern away from singleton though, even though I only plan to ever make one of these EntryPoint objects.

```
class EntryPoint
{

    /* Intentionally defined this way to discourage creation */
    EntryPoint(const EntryPoint &); // undefined & private
    EntryPoint& operator=(const EntryPoint &); // undefined & private

    // public
    EntryPoint()
    {
        /* All of the action is performed here! */
    }

    /* Other supporting functions */
}

// The easier to understand main function!
int main()
{
    EntryPoint * ep = new EntryPoint(); // transfer control to the entrypoint
    delete ep;
}
```

One of the reasons I was thinking I would need all these singletons is I plan to create a larger architecture that would support modular plugin-type applications. I also wanted more error-checking and memory protection to minimize memory leaks. I was happy to find that the cross-platform Qt (http://qt.nokia.com/) offers a guarded pointer and other cool features.

Comment: It sounds like `const` should do thetrick. But no, I don't think this is a good idea. Singletons are bad enough in their "normal" incarnation. Making them even more complex is only going to come back and bite you. Why do you have all these singletons anyway? The simplest way to control instantiation order is to stop making half your variables static/globals/singletons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `Singleton::GetInstance` directly?  Why do you need to store it in a (readonly) global?  This solves dependency issues as well.

Comment: +1 This is how I would call the Singleton GetInstance method too.

Comment: Half of me wants to know if it possible. But what I am trying to do is separate instantiation from access. My feeling is that someday I may create an AccessManager class that would be responsible for speeding up the access to global data (which may require querying a database, who knows) using caching techniques or something more complicated. 

Right now its not so bad because its simple, but I don't want to be in a situation where it becomes difficult to optimize because I have many calls to Singleton::GetInstance() all throughout the codebase.

Comment: Can you create a class (or several classes) with static methods such as `GetGraphicsEngine` and `GetInputEngine` which, for now, call `Singleton::GetInstance`?

Comment: @Tommy: a better solution is to *not make it a singleton in the first place*

Comment: @jalf, Agreed.  [character limit]

Answer (score 1):

Only allow access by calling:

```
Singleton::GetInstance
```

Enforce this by making your copy and assignment constructors private

```
private:
   Singleton(){}
   Singleton(Singleton const&){}; //copy ctor private
   Singleton& operator=(Singleton const&){};
```

Comment: and Singleton::GetInstance is static